# C# ActiveSelection

Tags: c#, ms-project

I am new to C# but I would like to develop an add-in for ms-project.
I would like to build the same function in the statusBar than Excel
So what I try to do is each time I change the selection of cells, I launch this small program:

```
        MSProject.Selection selection;
        MSProject.Tasks SelectedTask=null;
        string affiche;
        selection = Application.ActiveSelection;
        SelectedTask = selection.Tasks;
        if (SelectedTask != null)
        {
           value= SelectedTask.Count.ToString();
           this.Application.StatusBar = value;
        }
```

But nothing has happened. Would someone have an idea to help me?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: toxicboomboom on a broomstick? I'll bet you're not a typo **Witch**.. right? But like to blow up stuff with toxic thingies in a lab... Anyway... create a minimal working example.. and **"boum"**..there we go... shooting your question into the SO environment. And BTW.. if you got time besides blowing things up... finish the tour ;-)

Comment: This code resides in the `WindowSelectionChange` event, right? How about instead of just putting the count of tasks in the StatusBar, add more text so that it's obvious. A single digit might be easy to miss. FWIW, the StatusBar text is shown just right of the middle of the screen--NOT at the far left as with Excel.